# Generating a long byte array without repeated sub-array of given size

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

I would like to generate a long byte array where there is no repeated subsequence of size `N`. N is small, usually between 3 and 8.

Evidently generating an arbitrarily long array isn't feasible: after about `2^(8*N)` bytes there will be `2^(8*N)` subsequences already present so there won't be any unique ones left to use (since there are 2^(8*N) unique byte sequences of size `N`). Now this is an upper bound on the length of such an array, but not necessarily a lower bound). I don't need the longest possible sequence or anything like that: 1,000,000 values for `N == 4` is probably sufficient for example, but at least it should be possible to detect when the sequence is too long for uniqueness under some generation strategy.

Ideally the generation strategy is simple, nothing like checking each previous subsequence when adding each byte.

I put Java for concreteness since that's where I'm using it at the moment, but the concept is really applicable to any language.

Comment: What did you try? This is a programming help site, not a problem solving site.

Comment: If I understand correctly your task, 2^N is not right above estimation. For instance, for N = 2 we have 00110 sequence. For N=3: 000111010

Comment: Is a (prefix of) a de Bruijn sequence OK? Over the alphabet of bytes of course, not bits which is the most common. They may not be the easiest valid sequences to generate though

Comment: @egorlitvinenko - you are right, the bound was totally off, I fixed it above. In particular, for `N == 4` it seems that `2^32 + 3` is an upper bound on the length of a unique sequence (since at that point every one of the 2^32 unique sequences will have appeared once, under the condition there are no duplicates, by pigeonhole).

Comment: @AlKepp - I used an incrementing sequence of `1, 2, 3...` but this runs out after 256 bytes. Evidently I could then use a sequence of even numbers, or odd numbers, or better some increment relatively prime to 256, but these all "tap out" relatively quickly! This is definitely a programming problem solving site (I'm not sure where you got a different impression?). I have solved many problems for others and in exchange they have solved many for me :).

Comment: @user3386109 - indeed, but in addition to being slow, it isn't clear how to proceed. The hash table tells you which bytes you _can't_ add but most of the time you can add many bytes and it doesn't help you with that. You could certainly get into a case where you can't any byte to the current sequence, but the sequence is much shorter than possible because you made mistakes adding earlier bytes. A rule like "add the lowest byte the hash table allows at least step" actually results in a really short sequence like `0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,3,...,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,???`.

Comment: Note how it paints itself into a corner almost immediately: it can't add anything after the final `0,0,0` because each byte has already appeared in that context, because the sequence is badly constructed (I guess you could backtrack at this point...).

Comment: @user3386109 - yes, in fact it's a technique I'm using now for long sequences. It kind of sucks because it requires keeping 1,000,000 values in memory at that point just to generate the next value, which because of Java memory overhead ends up being close to 100 MB. Generating it formulaically would be much better! This approach also doesn't have an obvious upper bound, so it may fail unexpectedly at runtime for different seeds.

Comment: @user33 - in one test I got 5 duplicates with 1,000,000 elements and N=4.

Comment: @harold - your comment is the answer. Write it up briefly if you want (here's a link to a [Java implementation](http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2011/02/de-bruijn-sequence-in-constant-amortized-time/) even), or I'll do it later if you don't.

Comment: @harold - I wrote up your answer below with code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key observation, made by user [harold in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209600/generating-a-long-byte-array-without-repeated-sub-array-of-given-size/47234229#comment81368660_47209600), is that you can create a maximal sequence without repeating elements with a [de Bruijn sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence) of order `N`.

Such a sequence (they are not unique) contains every possible N-element subsequence exactly once, so will be a maximal sequence without N-element repeating subsequences.

The remaining question then is whether it is feasible to generate prefixes of such sequences fairly simply, and the answer is yes.

Following the method described in this [blog post](http://royvanrijn.com/blog/2011/02/generating-de-bruijn-sequences-and-lyndon-words/) one can generate all [Lyndon Words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyndon_word) of size N or less, in lexicographic order, and concatenate all those that have lengths dividing `N` to create the array we want.

In Java, with the alphabet simply being the 256 byte values, the code from the above link is adapted to deal with `byte[]` of a fixed length, as follows:

```
/**
 * Use an order-n de-Bruijn sequence to fill a byte array such that no n-length sub-array is repeated.
 */
public static void trucatedDeBruijnBytes(int n, byte[] arr) {
    int written = generateLyndonBytes(1, 1, 256, new byte[n + 1], arr, 0);
    if (written != arr.length) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Can't generate a unique sequence of length " + arr.length + ", max is " + written);
    }
}

private static int generateLyndonBytes(int t, int p, int k, byte[] a, byte[] output, int oidx) {
    if (t == a.length) {
        if((a.length-1)%p==0) {
            int len = Math.min(p, output.length - oidx);
            System.arraycopy(a, 1, output, oidx, len);
            oidx += len;
        }
    } else {
        a[t] = a[t-p]; 
        assert a[t] < k;
        if ((oidx = generateLyndonBytes(t+1,p, k, a, output, oidx)) == output.length) {
            return oidx;
        }
        for(int j = (a[t-p] & 0xFF) + 1; j < k; j++) {
            assert(j >= 0 && j < k);
            a[t] = (byte)j;
            assert a[t] < k;
            if ((oidx = generateLyndonBytes(t+1,t, k, a, output, oidx)) == output.length) {
                return oidx;
            }
        }
    }
    return oidx;
}
```

This can probably be further optimized, but it is already relatively efficient: it only uses a small amount of fixed state (the `byte[] a` array, which has size `N + 1`) plus a limited amount of recursion (generally up to `N + 1` calls deep) and a bit of math to generate all the values "in place". Much better than solutions that keep a hash of all seen `N`-sequences to do de-duplication!

For the curious, here's what the first bit of the sequence for `N == 2` looks like:

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 4, 0, 5, 0, 6, 0, 7, 0, 8, 0, 9, 0, 10, 0, 11, 0, 12, 0, 13, 0, 14, 0, ..., 125, 0, 126, 0, 127, 0, -128, 0, -127, ..., 0, -3, 0, -2, 0, -1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, ...]
```

So `0` followed by a simple incrementing sequence `0, i, 0, i + 1, ...` for 512 bytes then the sequence `1, i, 1, i + 1, ...` and so on.